# Windows PowerShell ISE - Remove new line when outputting to file

Tags: powershell, newline

I'm new to PowerShell.

I am outputting to a file and keep getting new lines. I'm not sure how to remove the newline function.
e.g.

```
"<Text> -", <Variable> | Add-Content <FilePath>
```

gives me:

```
<text>
<Variable>
```

What I'm after is

```
<Text> - <Variable> <Newline>
```

Comment: Though I didn't get the actual code you are trying to run, you can try to join the string using `-join` operator. Please share the complete command line that you are trying and also, please use code tag wherever you want to include the code or command line in the question.

Comment: Try replacing `,` with `+`

Answer (score 2):

`"<Text> -", <Variable>`, due to use of `,` - the array-construction operator - creates a *2-element array*, and the elements of an array each become their own line on output (via `Add-Content`).

In order to create a *single string*, you have several options:

```
$var = 'foo'  # sample variable

"<Text> - $var" | Add-Content <FilePath> # string expansion

'{0} - {1}' -f '<Text>', $var | Add-Content <FilePath> # -f, the .NET string-formatting operator

'<Text> - ' + $var | Add-Content <FilePath>  # string concatenation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below sample code. This example will help you:

```
$Test = "test"
"<Text> -", $Test -join "" | Add-Content "Test.txt"
```